# Derivatives of the Dirac delta function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

From what I understand the Dirac's Delta derivatives have the meaning
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta^{(k)}(x)\phi(x)dx=(-1)^k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\phi^{(k)}(x)dx$$
Assuming, of course that the function $\phi$ is differentiable up to order $k$. If that's true, you can then say
$$\phi^{(k)}(x_0)=(-1)^k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta^{(k)}(x-x_0)\phi(x)dx$$
Is this correct? And also, could it be useful in any circumstance?

Comment: Sure. I don't know what you mean when you say "useful", though.

Comment: It follows from the definition.

Comment: @Ian, useful means that if you knew this you could do something better or  more easily than if you didn´t

Answer (score 1):

It is correct provided that one understand the notation $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\phi(x)\ dx$ correctly. This is by no means an integral and $\delta$ is not a function with real variables.

Also, one should specify in what function space is the function $\phi$ so that your identities would make sense.

---

*Any* distribution $T$ is infinitely differentiable in the sense of distribution by the definition
$$
\langle \partial^\alpha T,\varphi\rangle:=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\langle \partial^\alpha\varphi,T\rangle.
$$

However, it is not true that $T$ has arbitrary order *weak derivative*. For instance, the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is not weakly differentiable but its distributional derivative is the delta function.

---

<s>I have never seen the word "derivable" used in that way before.</s> (Due to change of OP)

---

In the theory of electromagnetism, the first derivative of the delta function represents a point magnetic dipole situated at the origin. As for the higher order distributional derivatives, can I say that it is useful for demonstrating an example of distributions of which the $k$-th order derivative can be explicitly calculated?

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my first language, I've learnt maths mostly in Spanish :(. What would be the word for "a function that can be derived"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function

Comment: I've never heard "weak derivative" as distinct from "distributional derivative" before.

Comment: @Ian https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/

Comment: Fair enough. I still have usually seen the opposite convention, where "weak derivative" and "distributional derivative" are synonymous. We can still talk about the weak derivative "being" a locally integrable function where (from this perspective) we really mean that it, as a distribution, can be represented as integration against a locally integrable function.